# Reactive form validation

Tags: angular, types, angular-validation

[image]I have implemented validation for text-box control using formBuilder.Same form is used for adding new entry and editing existing record.
But when I come to page through edit button click,Textbox contains prefilled
value. In this case, also It shows me an error until and unless I touched it and edit record.

My code:

```
<input type="text" #modelName  class="form-control" name="modelName" 
       (input)="objAssetModel.AssetModelName=modelName.value"
        value="{{objAssetModel.AssetModelName}}" 
        placeholder="Enter Model Name"
        [ngClass]="{'error':!modelForm.controls['modelName'].valid
        [formControl]="modelForm.controls['modelName']"/>


<div *ngIf="modelForm.controls['modelName'].hasError('required') && modelForm.controls['modelName'].touched" 
     class="alert alert-danger">Please enter Model Name
</div>
```

In constroctur I wrote following code

```
this.modelForm = formbuilderObj.group({
   'modelName': [this.objAssetModel.AssetModelName, Validators.required],
   'cboManufacturer': [this.objAssetModel.AssetModelManufacturerName, Validators.required]
})
```

how to handle such case?

Comment: Check if the form control is touched or dirty. `[ngClass]="{'error':!modelForm.controls['modelName'].valid && (modelForm.controls['modelName'].dirty || modelForm.controls['modelName'].touched}"`

Comment: @miguel your solution works fine for edit mode but also affect save mode